# Intermittent access in China to Google App Engine app with custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

Here's a strange one.  We have a Google App Engine (GAE) app and a custom domain http://www.tradeos.com CNAME'd to ghs.google.com.  In China we regularly get no response whatsoever from the server for 20 minutes or so then it works fine for a a while, sometimes for a few hours.

Other non-Chinese sites like CNN seem to work continuously so it's not a general problem with the international Internet going down. From other countries we see no problem.

By the way the non-custom Google domains x.appspot.com don't seem to be accessible at all presumably blocked by the Great Firewall.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: So what solution did you settle on finally? Did reverse DNS work or did you have to switch away from GAE?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a Great Firewall (GFW) of China issue. Google App Engine keeps switching IPs and some of them are blocked in China.  We got around it temporarily using CloudFlare although that has other problems like occasional 502 errors.

Answer (score 0):

You konw GFW,and Google CNAME is blocked in China.You can switch CNAME IP,or use  reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse proxy to get around this problem. Do you have access to a server running apache or nginx? If so, you can configure that to be your reverse proxy. Otherwise there are some SAAS that will reverse proxy for you.